# python use ctypes to pass 2-d array into c function

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I want to use C to deal with some computations. For example, I have a C function of adding two matrix:

```
// mat_add.c
#include <stdlib.h>

void matAdd(int ROW, int COL, int x[][COL], int y[][COL], int z[][COL]){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++){
            z[i][j] = x[i][j] + y[j][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Then I compiled it into .so file:
`gcc -shared -fPIC mat_add.c -o mat_add.so`

And in python:

```
# mat_add_test.py
import ctypes
import numpy as np

def cfunc(x, y):
    nrow, ncol = x.shape
    
    objdll = ctypes.CDLL('./mat_add.so')
    
    func = objdll.matAdd
    func.argtypes = [
        ctypes.c_int,
        ctypes.c_int,
        np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.int, ndim=2, shape=(nrow, ncol)),
        np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.int, ndim=2, shape=(nrow, ncol)),
        np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.int, ndim=2, shape=(nrow, ncol))
    ]
    func_restype = None
    
    z = np.empty_like(x)
    func(nrow, ncol, x, y, z)
    return z


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]], dtype=np.int)
    y = np.array([[2, 2], [5, 6]], dtype=np.int)
    z = cfunc(x, y)
    print(z)
    print('end')
```

Executed this python file, I obtained:

```
$ python mat_add_test.py 
[[                  3                   4]
 [8386863780988286322 7813586346238636153]]
end
```

The first row of return matrix is correct, but the second row is wrong. I guess that I don't successfully update the value in `z`, but I have no idea where the problem is.
Can anyone help? Very thanks!

Comment: Your type in C is the wrong length. It works if I try your code with the arrays declared as `long`. Probably there is some correct procedure with an appropriate `typedef` - I am not suggesting hard-coding `long` but it suffices to demonstrate the point.

Comment: Aside from that, a small bug in your C: `y[j][j]` should be `y[i][j]`

Comment: `x.dtype` reports `dtype('int64')`

Comment: I change my .c file from `int` to `long`, and it works! I forget that np.int is difference to int in c. Very thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. To discover the problem I just put a printf statement into the C code - `printf("i=%d j=%d x=%d y=%d\n", i, j, x[i][j], y[i][j]);` writes `i=0 j=0 x=1 y=2` `i=0 j=1 x=0 y=0` `i=1 j=0 x=2 y=2` `i=1 j=1 x=0 y=0`. So then it becomes fairly obvious.

Comment: Okay, if you `#include <stdint.h>` you can use type `int64_t`. Probably in the Python code it would be good to use `dtype=np.int64` explicitly.

Comment: By the way, If the type in C is wrong, why the result of first row is still correct?

Comment: It is seeing the `x` values as `1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0`, and similarly for `y`. For the first four pairs, it performs the addition, giving `3, 0, 4, 0`. This affects only the first row of the output array in Python, and by chance the output values are correct because of no need for carry.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. `x` is a 2*2 matrix, why it is seening the `x` values as `1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0`?

Comment: Really it is contiguous values in memory, so you can also think of it as 1d. The 2d array simply gives a convenient way of indexing it.

Comment: And for example the number 1 in 64-bit on a little-endian machine will be equivalent to a 1 followed by 0 if you treat the array pointer as 32-bit.

Comment: Oh I understand, I pass a 64bit number into c function, but `x` is only 32bit. So a 64bit number is divided into 2 numbers in `x`, that is `1` and `0`. Is it right?

Comment: I added an answer with an explanation which should help to clarify it.

Comment: If we want a main() in mat_add.c for self-testing, how do you declare and initialize x and y in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handling of 2d array in the question is correct.  The only problem (apart from a typo in how the C code indexes the `y` array - `y[j][j]` should be `y[i][j]`) is that `np.int` is `np.int64` so this does not correspond to a C `int`.

To ensure that the types match, an explicit length can be specified in both languages.

In Python: use `np.int32` or `np.int64` explicitly (instead of `np.int`).

In C: `#include <stdint.h>` and then use `int32_t` or `int64_t` correspondingly (possibly via a `typedef`), instead of `int`.

Then the problem goes away.

For `ROW` and `COL`, these are call by value so it is less important (provided of course that the values do not overflow).

**What is happening here**

In reality a 2d array is still just a 1d sequence of values in memory; the 2 dimensions are just a convenient way to index it.

So in numpy the arrays just before calling C are (in hex):

```
0000000000000001 0000000000000002 0000000000000003 0000000000000004  <== x
0000000000000002 0000000000000002 0000000000000005 0000000000000006  <== y
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU  <== z
```

where `U` means undefined / uninitialised data

but in the C code (assuming little endian), treating the arrays as 32-bit, it sees:

```
inputs
00000001 00000000 00000002 00000000 00000003 00000000 00000004 00000000  <== x
00000002 00000000 00000002 00000000 00000005 00000000 00000006 00000000  <== y
UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU  <== z at start
```

Then the C code loops over the first 4 elements of each, performing additions, so this produces:

```
00000003 00000000 00000004 00000000 UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU UUUUUUUU  <== z at end
```

and back in numpy using a 64-bit int type, now we see:

```
0000000000000003 0000000000000004 UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU  <== output z
```

Interpreted as a 2-d array, this is `array([[3, 4], [whatever, whatever]])`

Comment: I fully understand why I was wrong and why it appeared some strange numbers. Thank you for your patient explanation!

Comment: @Chun-YeLu I wrote the explanation in the answer with wrong lengths -- 16 and 32 bit (4 and 8 hex digits) - now corrected to 32 and 64 bit (8 and 16 hex digits) -- although the principle is of course exactly the same.

Comment: That's okay ;) I'm not familiar with hexadecimal so I have not noticed about this.